# Text as Tikz to be Centered

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have copied and pasted a few formats[and packages], and now I do not know which is for which. Especially, I want to make the text in the box to be CENTERED, in the middle of the line. Can you please tell where to edit the code?

```
\definecolor{aurometalsaurus}{rgb}{0.43, 0.5, 0.5}
\tikzstyle{section style} = [anchor=east ,thick,rounded corners=11pt,inner sep=20pt,draw=aurometalsaurus,fill=white]

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{10pt}{20pt}{<after-sep>}
\titleformat{\section}[block]%
{\gdef\sectionlabel{}\large\bfseries}%
{\gdef\sectionlabel{\thesection.\space}}{0pt}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[thick,aurometalsaurus](0,0) -- (\textwidth,0);
\node[section style] at (0,0) {\sectionlabel#1};
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

when I begin a section:

```
\section{Hi there}
```

the Hi there is not centered, only the "e" of there is at the center of the text line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `anchor=east` from the `section style` style, and move the node to the middle of the line. Generally, if you do `\draw (a) --node{x} (b);`, then `x` is placed midway between `a` and `b`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{aurometalsaurus}{rgb}{0.43, 0.5, 0.5}
\tikzset{section style/.style={thick,rounded corners=11pt,inner sep=20pt,draw=aurometalsaurus,fill=white}}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{10pt}{20pt}{<after-sep>}
\titleformat{\section}[block]%
{\gdef\sectionlabel{}\large\bfseries}%
{\gdef\sectionlabel{\thesection.\space}}{0pt}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[thick,aurometalsaurus](0,0) --node[section style] {\sectionlabel#1} (\textwidth,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\section{Hi there}

\end{document}
```